# Coin Flipping/Card picking program not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given a task to write a program in a pretty basic python style. The program is supposed to ask the user whether they want to 1. Flip a coin, or 2. Pick a card.

Then uses an IF to check what the user picked. If it was one, it's supposed to randomly generate heads or tails and print what it got.

If the choice was 2, it asks the user to choose a suit, then generates a number between 1 and 13 (ace to king) and prints 'You picked [value] of [suit]'

```
import random

print('1. Flip a coin')
print('2. Pick a card')
choice = int(input('Enter a coice :'))
if choice == 1:
    Hort = ''
    HorT == random.randint(0,1)
    if HorT == "0":
       print('You got Heads')
    elif HorT == "1":
       print('You got Tails')
elif choice == 2:
    print()
    print('1. Hearts')
    print('2. Clubs')
    print('3. Diamonds')
    print('4. Spades')
    print()
    suitno = ''
    suitno ==int(input('Choose a suit'))
    if suitno == "1":
        suit == "Hearts"
    elif suitno == '2':
        suit == 'Clubs'
    elif suitno == '3':
        suit == 'Diamonds'
    elif suitno == '4':
        suit == 'Spades'
    value = ''
    value == random.randint(1,13)
    print()
    print('You picked', value, 'of', suit)
```

as you can see, it's basic but I was asked to follow the pseudo-code as closely as I could. It stops right at the beginning. I enter then number for the choice, and it just ends.

EDIT: I have amended the code to show what I have changed.

Comment: And what version of Python do you use?

Comment: @traceur 95% chance Python 3, due to the `print` and OP casting `input` to an integer.

Comment: `choice = int(input('Enter a coice :'))` <- `choice` is integer. `if choice == '1':` <- Test equality of integer with string: always false

Comment: @AlexThornton I think that was a sanity check to see if OP was trying to run this in Python 2.

Comment: You only changed `'1'` to `1`, but not `'2'` to `2`!

Comment: It's a little odd that you have to choose the suit to "pick" a card... I'm pretty sure that if you have to pick a card from a deck, the suit is just as random as the rank.  Are you sure that was what you were asked to do, or was that how you interpreted the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Common mistakes:**

1. `==` used for comparison and **not** for assignment e.g `4 == 4` is `True`
2. variable of `int` type will **never** be equal to string e.g `4 == '4'` is `False`. This is the reason why your `if` statements didn't execute.
3. There's no need in variable initialization before getting `input()`.
4. It usually better to have `else` if you have `elif`.

**Dirty, but complete fix:**

```
import random

print('1. Flip a coin')
print('2. Pick a card')

choice = int(input('Enter a coice: '))

if choice == 1:
    HorT = random.randint(0,1)
    if HorT == 0:
        print('You got Heads')
    else:
        print('You got Tails')

elif choice == 2:
    print()
    print('1. Hearts')
    print('2. Clubs')
    print('3. Diamonds')
    print('4. Spades')
    print()
    suitno = int(input('Choose a suit: '))
    if suitno == 1:
        suit = "Hearts"
    elif suitno == 2:
        suit = 'Clubs'
    elif suitno == 3:
        suit = 'Diamonds'
    else:
        suit = 'Spades'

    value = random.randint(1, 13)
    print()
    print('You picked', value, 'of', suit)
```

It could be written more concisely, but it is `pretty basic python style` program :)

**[@Two-Bit Alchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588818/two-bit-alchemist) - @vaultah version:**

```
import random

print('1. Flip a coin')
print('2. Pick a card')

choice = int(input('Enter a choice: '))

if choice == 1:
    outcomes = ('heads', 'tails')
    print('You got {}.'.format(random.choice(outcomes)))

else:
    suits = ('Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades')
    print()
    for index, element in enumerate(suits, start=1):
        print('{}. {}'.format(index, element))

    suitno = int(input('Choose a suit: '))
    value = random.randint(1, 13)
    print('\nYou picked', value, 'of', suits[suitno-1])
```

Comment: That said, there's a lot of other refactoring that would help, and quite a bit of simplification. Most immediately, no `if/elif` trees have an `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for that. I noticed it and fixed it before I read this though... Still not working. Still stops in the same place, without printing the Heads or Tails. The card option doesn't work either... It prints "you picked  of  "

Comment: @user3529054 There are lots of problems in your code (e.g. there is a  difference between `=` and `==` in Python). It's easier if you read a book for beginners instead of starting to write code that has an error in every second line.

Comment: @traceur thanks very much. I made some of the same adjustments you've made so that most of it worked... But I still couldn't get a couple of things to work. Your corrections have made it very easy to help me see where I went wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @user3529054 Sounds like you should accept this answer?

Comment: `enumerate` accepts a `start` keyword argument so you don't have to do `index+1`, just use `start=1`.

Comment: Since you decided to fully refactor this, feel free to cannibalize [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23043579/2588818) as a more explicit alternative on the coin flip problem. I might also suggest `suits` should be a tuple (immutable), but that might be splitting hairs.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems:

```
choice = int(input('Enter a coice :'))
if choice == '1':
```

Here you are comparing integer choice and string '1' values.

And the second problem that you have a lot of constructions that looks like:

```
if a == '1':
   some_statement
elif a == '2:
   some statement
...
```

Such switch can be formed in python with dictionaries:

```
import random

coin_sides = {
    '1': 'Heads',
    '2': 'Tails'
}

card_suits = {
    '1': 'Hearts',
    '2': 'Clubs',
    '3': 'Diamonds',
    '4': 'Spades'
}

print('1. Flip a coin')
print('2. Pick a card')

choice = input('Enter a coice :')

if choice == '1':
    side = random.randint(0,1)
    print 'You got {0}'.format(coin_sides.get(side))

elif choice == '2':
    print()
    print('1. Hearts')
    print('2. Clubs')
    print('3. Diamonds')
    print('4. Spades')
    print()

    suitno = input('Choose a suit')

    suit = card_suits.get(suitno)

    value = random.randint(1,13)

    print()

    print('You picked', value, 'of', suit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23043560/2588818) quite adequately critique your card-picking design, I'll only post the bit I had about your coin flip.

#### Flip a Coin

The outcome of this program is a statment:

> `You got {heads|tails}`.

Thus, we are only interested in the strings `'heads'` or `'tails'`. Since **explicit is better than implicit**:

```
outcomes = ('heads', 'tails')
print('You got {}.'.format(random.choice(outcomes)))
```

is all you need.

Comment: I just wanted to demonstrate dictionaries usage, but your variant is much more elegant.

Comment: @A.Haaji Your answer approximates what I was going to say about the card-picking because it's a data structure issue (the `var1`, `var2`, ..., `varN` anti-pattern). For that bit, what I posted would have been similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another restructured version:

```
from random import choice

COINS = ["Heads", "Tails"]
FACES = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
SUITS = ["Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"]

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= value) and (hi is None or value <= hi):
                return value
        except ValueError:
            pass

def do_menu(prompt, options):
    print("")
    for i,option in enumerate(options, 1):
        print("{:>3}. {}".format(i, option))
    return get_int(prompt, 1, len(options)) - 1

def main():
    while True:
        option = do_menu("> ", ["Flip a coin", "Pick a card", "Quit"])
        if option == 0:
            print("\nYou flipped {}.".format(choice(COINS)))
        elif option == 1:
            suit = SUITS[do_menu("Pick a suit: ", SUITS)]
            print("\nYou picked {} of {}".format(choice(FACES), suit))
        else:
            print("\nGoodbye!")
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```